# Why is Jackson inserting _children and _value into my JSON Response from Jersey?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am in the process of converting the main JSON library for my application from `net.sf` to `Jackson`.

For my REST endpoints, before the change of libraries, I was generating a `Response` object like this:

```
...
JsonArray arr = JSONArray.fromObject(obj);
return Response.ok(arr).build();
```

After switching to Jackson, that same code looked like this:

```
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayNode arr = mapper.valueToTree(obj);
return Response.ok(arr).build();
```

However, when I query this rest endpoint now, the JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "_children": [
        {
            "_children": {
                "@id": {
                    "_value": "myID"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

instead of

```
[
    {
        "@id": "myID"
    }
]
```

Why is this happening? It is breaking the front end, because the front end is not expecting the JSON to be structured that way. My only workaround so far has been to do an `arr.toString()` on the `ArrayNode` object inside the `Response.ok()` call.

Comment: Afaik `Response.ok(obj)` already converts the passed object to json so just `Response.ok(obj).build();` should be sufficient. Basically you're building another object (which represents a JSON tree but isn't one in a strict sense) and since `ArrayNode` has a property `_children` you get what you see.

Comment: You could use `mapper.writeValueAsString(obj)` instead.